# Galleria Fatal error: Could not extract a stage height from the CSS / Multiple Galleria and Display:none;

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use two tab with `display: none;` or `display: block;` style if I don't click to videos or pictures tab in 1 minute then error appears and it say couldn't extract a stage height.

galleria is a image/video gallery slider js based.
http://galleria.io/ link of galleria.
How can I remove error function in JavaScript or how can i deactive it

CODES>>
TABMENU JAVASCRIPT

```
function tabmenu(buttonObject){ 
    var value = buttonObject.value
    var target = document.getElementById(value);

    if(target) {
       var siblings = target.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("tabmenu");
       for(i=0;i<siblings.length;i++){
          siblings[i].style.display = "none";
       }
       target.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

TABMENU HTML

```
    <button class="tabmenu" onclick="tabmenu(this);" value="picture">Picture</button>
    <button class="tabmenu" onclick="tabmenu(this);" value="video">Video</button>
    <div id="picture" class="style1">
<a href="image link">
<img
src="image link",
data-title="Title"
data-description="Description"
>
</a>
<a href="image link">
<img
src="image link",
data-title="Title"
data-description="Description"
>
</a>
    <script>
    Galleria.loadTheme('js/galleria.classic.min.js');
    Galleria.run('#picture');
    Galleria.configure({lightbox: true});
    </script>
    </div>
        <div id="video" class="style1">
    <a href="youtube video link">
    <img src="image link">
    </a>
        <a href="youtube video link">
    <img src="image link">
    </a>
    <script>
    Galleria.loadTheme('js/galleria.classic.min.js');
    Galleria.run('#video');
    Galleria.configure({lightbox: true});
    </script>
        </div>
```

STYLE1.CSS

```
    .style1{display:none;}
#picture{height:400px;width:590px;}
#video{height:400px;width:590px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Found Answer :) its simple just you should add

```
Galleria.configure({
wait: true
});
```

that script to below the galleria.
it makes galleria wait infinity time.